# Relative path using Level hierarchy(../../)

Tags: java, xml, relative-path

I want to use the **relative path** in `xml` files in our project. I have the files in the following location.

```
D:/SDC-Builds/SRDM2.3.0/SRDM/Svr/IdP/IdPserver/conf/attribute-r.xml
```

I have other xml file which needs to ref the above location, I use the following relative path to be independent of machines and folder names.
In D:/SDC-Builds/SRDM2.3.0/SRDM/Svr/IdP/IdPserver/others/service.xml, i am using the code like below

**service.xml**

```
<srv:ConfigurationResource="../../../../../../IdP/IdPserver/conf/attribute-r.xml">
</srv>
```

Please tell me am i using proper convention to refer the attribute-r.xml ?

Comment: 'I have other xml file which needs to ref the above location' - What's the location of the other xml file?

Comment: @PaulStatham Please look into my above updated query.

Comment: I think i have answered the question @NiklasB. Please let me know any thing else should be added.

Comment: Never mind, I must have problems with my eyes

Comment: Is it not just '../conf/attribute-r.xml'

Comment: basically, how to represent "D:/SDC-Builds/SRDM2.3.0/SRDM/Svr/IdP/IdPserver/conf/attribute-r.xml" by using "../../../" instead of mentioning D:/SDC-Builds/ etc..

Comment: As I said '../conf/attribute-r.xml', .. for one level above 'others' so cwd is now IdPServer, then reference conf/attribute-r.xml from there.

Answer (score 0):

If your Project Root Directory is SRDM, then you need to get back from your executable path.

Say you have your exe file at SRDM/Svr/bin/EXECUTABLE.exe then,

you need to mention in xml as

```
<srv:ConfigurationResource="../IdP/IdPserver/conf/attribute-r.xml"></srv>
```

ie. Current working directory is SRDM/Svr/bin/ and from that you need to get back up to common junction[Svr] in your case.

Comment: Can you please provide some additional details? like current working directory. You just print the working directory using you application itself(please don't say theoretically).

Comment: D:/SDC-Builds/SRDM2.3.0/SRDM/Svr is my current working directory

Comment: Then your relative path should be like **"./IdP/IdPserver/conf/attribute-r.xml"** because the source file is in same juction so from current path(./) we have to provide the xml file path.

Comment: but it is not able read it. thats why i am using ../../Idp/Idpserver/conf/attribute-r.xml

Comment: hello @D D Sridhar, is it working only one (.) or (..)  in "./IdP/IdPserver/conf/attribute-r.xml"

Comment: To debug this issue. Program wise print the path of the xml like following. String fullpath = current working path.append("IdP/IdPserver/conf/attribute-r.xml");. Now you can find out where is the real issue.

Comment: @D D Sridhar, Can i get solve it by using ./IdP/IdPserver/conf/attribute-r.xml single dot(.)

Comment: ..(double dot) means it will move to parent directory .(single Dot) is the current working directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64852/discussion-between-majji-and-d-d-sridhar).